# Docmd.OpenReport showing first record but not rest in a record set

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using the code below to go thru a recordset and send individual reports to a person. Everything is working but the preview on the openreport on all but the first report are blank. Trying to figure out why if it sends the correct report to the person. It acts like it's opening a report and shows it then closes it but there's nothing but a blank page. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

```vb
    Private Sub Command0_Click()


    Dim daDb As DAO.Database
    Dim daRs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sSql As String

    sSql = "SELECT * FROM EmailedContributions;"

    Set daDb = CurrentDb
    Set daRs = daDb.OpenRecordset(sSql, dbOpenSnapshot)

    Do Until daRs.EOF

    Debug.Print daRs!MemberID
    Debug.Print daRs!EmailName
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Copy Of IRS Contribution Letter", acViewPreview, , "MemberID = " & daRs!MemberID,   acWindowNormal
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Copy Of IRS Contribution Letter", acFormatPDF, daRs!EmailName, , , "IRS Contributions", "Attached are your contributions", False
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "Copy Of IRS Contribution Letter"

    Debug.Print daRs!EmailName
    daRs.MoveNext

    Loop

    daRs.Close
    Set daRs = Nothing
    Set daDb = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: Without seeing your report binding nobody will help you.

Comment: I’ve removed the problem. Not sure how or I’d share.